# TFS Migration from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 When Both Have Collections in Use

Tags: tfs

We need to migrate projects in TFS from one server to another.  On source server we have TFS 2010 with several VS.NET projects in the DefaultCollection.  On the destination server, we have TFS 2013 with an empty DefaultCollection but 2 other collections in use by other developers.  Each instance of TFS has its own SQL Server.

The problem we face is how to take the DefaultCollection from the TFS 2010 server and place it on the TFS 2013 Server?

I'm aware of several articles about migration but have not found one that exactly fits our situation.  I appreciate any ideas anyone may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very straightforward scenario.

Something along these lines should work:

- Detach DefaultCollection from TFS 2010 using the admin console.
- Take a backup of your TFS 2010 DefaultCollection database
- Migrate the database to your TFS 2013 database server
- Attach the TFS 2010 DefaultCollection database in TFS 2013 via the admin console. As part of the attaching process, you should be able to rename it.

The team project collection database will be upgraded to TFS 2013 and made available to users. At that point, you can go back and clean up unneeded project collections and rename things if you'd like.

Always take backups before you attempt any sort of migration or upgrade. I always recommend performing the upgrade against a test environment first.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading in place before moving the collection.